# I have a WinXP machine with 2 ethernet ports. One is connected to a LAN, another is connected to a WAN. How do I make this work?

Tags: windows, nic, traffic-shaping

I have a WinXP machine which has 2 ethernet ports. The information I've found indicates that the first nic in the advanced settings list is the one that receives all traffic.

I'd like to configure them so that all traffic destined for a particular IP range goes to one nic and the rest goes to the other nic. Is that possible? If so, do I need additional software like zonealarm to shape the traffic?

Comment: I can't imagine any professional networking scenario that could correctly be answered with "Zone Alarm".

Comment: Are the two nics connected to the same network or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use static routes. See usage here:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_pro_addstaticroute.mspx?mfr=true